# NestJS / Vitest - Sequelize response id is null

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, nestjs, vitest

I'm trying to migrate Jest to Vitest with swc on my NestJS project.

I have a problem with Sequelize response :
I can't access to the `property.id` directly in my tests, I should set `raw: true` on the request to get the plain result and access to this property. This occur only after my vitest migration, but with jest I can access with `property.id`.

Sequelize is created in `database.index.ts` with `this.sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, SEQUELIZE_CONFIG);`

vitest.config.ts:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    swc.vite({ 
      tsconfigFile: './tsconfig.build.json',
    }),
  ],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    setupFiles: [
      resolve(__dirname, 'src/test/setup.ts'),
    ],
    globalSetup: [
      resolve(__dirname, 'src/test/global.ts'),
    ],
    alias: {
      'Services': resolve(__dirname, 'src/services'),
      'Database': resolve(__dirname, 'src/database'),
      'Controllers': resolve(__dirname, 'src/controllers'),
      'Utils': resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils'),
      'Framework': resolve(__dirname, 'src/framework'),
      'Providers': resolve(__dirname, 'src/providers'),
      'Guards': resolve(__dirname, 'src/guards'),
      'Decorators': resolve(__dirname, 'src/decorators'),
      'Filters': resolve(__dirname, 'src/filters'),
      'Managers': resolve(__dirname, 'src/managers'),
      'Modules': resolve(__dirname, 'src/modules'),
      'Tests': resolve(__dirname, 'src/test'),
      Core: resolve(__dirname, 'core/ts'),
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'Services': resolve(__dirname, 'src/services'),
      'Database': resolve(__dirname, 'src/database'),
      'Controllers': resolve(__dirname, 'src/controllers'),
      'Utils': resolve(__dirname, 'src/utils'),
      'Framework': resolve(__dirname, 'src/framework'),
      'Providers': resolve(__dirname, 'src/providers'),
      'Guards': resolve(__dirname, 'src/guards'),
      'Decorators': resolve(__dirname, 'src/decorators'),
      'Filters': resolve(__dirname, 'src/filters'),
      'Managers': resolve(__dirname, 'src/managers'),
      'Modules': resolve(__dirname, 'src/modules'),
      'Tests': resolve(__dirname, 'src/test'),
      Core: resolve(__dirname, 'core/ts'),
    },
  },
});
```

Request example where user.id is undefined :

```
    const user = await User.findByPk(newUser.id, {
      attributes: [
        'id',
        'username',
        'createdAt',
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: Role_DB,
          through: {
            attributes: [],
          },
          attributes: ['id', 'alias'],
        },
        {
          required: false,
          model: Society,
          as: 'societies',
          attributes: ['id'],
        }],
    });
```

Response :

```
{
  dataValues: {
    id: 1,
    username: 'voluptates-eos-esse',
    createdAt: 2023-08-31T07:20:33.000Z,
    roles: [],
    societies: [],
    lastConnection: 2023-08-31T07:20:33.156Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-08-31T07:20:33.156Z
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    id: 1,
    username: 'voluptates-eos-esse',
    createdAt: 2023-08-31T07:20:33.000Z,
    roles: [],
    societies: [],
    lastConnection: 2023-08-31T07:20:33.156Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-08-31T07:20:33.156Z
  },
  _changed: Set(0) {},
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    include: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    includeNames: [ 'roles', 'societies' ],
    includeMap: { roles: [Object], societies: [Object] },
    includeValidated: true,
    attributes: [ 'id', 'username', 'createdAt' ],
    raw: true
  },
  isNewRecord: false,
  roles: undefined,
  societies: undefined,
  id: undefined,
  username: undefined,
}
```

With my Jest branch, this request return :

```
{
      dataValues: {
        id: 3,
        username: 'est-aspernatur-cupiditate',
        createdAt: 2023-08-31T07:23:53.000Z,
        roles: [],
        societies: [],
        lastConnection: 2023-08-31T07:23:53.023Z,
        updatedAt: 2023-08-31T07:23:53.023Z
      },
      _previousDataValues: {
        id: 3,
        username: 'est-aspernatur-cupiditate',
        createdAt: 2023-08-31T07:23:53.000Z,
        roles: [],
        societies: [],
        lastConnection: 2023-08-31T07:23:53.023Z,
        updatedAt: 2023-08-31T07:23:53.023Z
      },
      _changed: Set(0) {},
      _options: {
        isNewRecord: false,
        _schema: null,
        _schemaDelimiter: '',
        include: [ [Object], [Object] ],
        includeNames: [ 'roles', 'societies' ],
        includeMap: { roles: [Object], societies: [Object] },
        includeValidated: true,
        attributes: [ 'id', 'username', 'createdAt' ],
        raw: true
      },
      isNewRecord: false,
      roles: [],
      societies: []
    }
```

Versions :

Node : 18.15.0
NestJS: 10
Vitest: 0.34.3
@swc/core: 1.3.80
unplugin-swc: 1.4.2
sequelize: 6.6.2
sequelize-typescript: 2.1.1

I tried to update Sequelize but I have the same result

Comment: Is it acceptable to use the result of `.get({ plain: true})` instead of a model instance itself?

Comment: We want use the result without `.get({ plain: true })`